# Nginx run javascript when url is opened by a user

Tags: javascript, nginx

Is it somehow possible to run a javascipt code from Nginx in the web page when a particular url is opened from a browser by a user? For example when user opens https://example.net/test/page, javascript is executed in that web page.

Current Nginx settings:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.net;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/example.net.ssl.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/example.net.ssl.error.log;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

How can I edit these settings in order to call a javascript from the "/path/to/file.js" to execute it only when user opens https://example.net/test/page ? In other pages script should't be executed. I would really appreciate any advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use nginx [SubFilter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) module to append a script to the document returned from the upstream. For example, you can replace the `</head>` tag with the `<script src="/path/to/script.js"></script></head>` string:

```
map $uri $script {
    # only when URI is '/test/page'
    /test/page  '<script src="/path/to/script.js"></script>';
    # default value will be an empty string
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        sub_filter '</head>' '$script</head>';
    }
    # only one special location to serve locally
    location = /path/to/script.js {
        alias /full/path/to/script.js;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Unfortunately I couldn't get it working.

In the /path/to/script.js I have such javascript code:

const pathname = window.location.pathname;
if (pathname.includes('/test/page/')) {
const slash = pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
const key = pathname.substring(slash);
window.location.replace('https://example.net/');
}

The main idea is to execute javascript code when user opens /test/page/ and then redirect it to the https://example.net/.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow get this aforementioned javascript working? When using my script, nginx sites-available does not pass the configuration test. Sub filter seems to be working fine if I add a simple console.log("script test"). It might be a case that this sub_filter does not completely support javascript functions. Maybe there are some other known alternatives how to feed this script to nginx?

Comment: I need to give it a test by myself, but I don't have time for that right now, sorry. Maybe I could tell you something a few days later.

Comment: No worries, I can wait a few days. In the meantime I am going to try it with the Nginx javascript module, although I am not really sure if such case is even possible with njs.
P.S. I am very new to Nginx and still trying to learn.

Comment: Hi! I still couldn't figure this one out. Are there any chances to somehow get it working?